# Apple Watch Siri problem: "Uh, oh. I lost the connection. Let me try that again"

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, siri

I have an Apple Watch Series 5, with all the latest updates but I have a weird problem.

Whenever I try to use Siri I nearly always get the response:

> "Uh, oh. I lost the connection. Let me try that again"

And since the last WatchOS update:

> "Sorry, once again." or "Sorry, one more time." or "Sorry, let me try that again."

Even for something as simple as setting a timer.  Similarly, upon trying to make a call using the watch I often get a "Call failed" message.

I am on the same WiFi connection and within Bluetooth range.

In another glitch that may or may not be related, if I say to Siri "Call Home", Siri will report a problem with the phone app, and then give me a button to tap the app to manually open it. (Except the button doesn't respond when tapped.)

I've tried re-pairing the watch and restored from backup. I've also tried force-restarting the watch. On the iPhone I reset the network setting but that did not help, either.

Does this sound like an issue that can be resolved in some way — or do I have a defective watch?

Comment: My impression is that there is a "hiccup" in the chain between the Bluetooth, iPhone, Apple Watch and my WiFi network. Siri, when attempting to respond to a query, will clip (Siri voice cuts out), at which point Siri says "Uh oh. Lost the connection". That said, the connection IS there because I can see the info. on the screen (i.e. a search result). Siri will then say "Let me try that again" at which point the action is completed (Siri reads the weather forecast or responds to whatever the request may have been). Does this sound like behavior that can be corrected — or a defective watch?

Comment: Update: I learned that most of the problems described above disappear if I turn off Bluetooth because it forces the watch to use WiFi. However, this begs the question why enabling Bluetooth on the watch results in such hit-or-miss success using Siri, sending/receiving calls, etc. I realize the Bluetooth range is short, but the watch basically has to be in the same room with the phone if both WiFi and Bluetooth are on. I'm still questioning why it can't self-manage the handoff between Bluetooth and WiFi more successfully — short of me manually intervening to "fix" the watch's poor performance?

Comment: Did you find a solution for the problem ? I am having the same issue and tried also any possibility. My Apple Watch 3 never had such problems. Maybe there is a hardware defect ?

Comment: I also have this exact issue. It's very annoying